# Nested Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to write a selector which will select
1. Input elements of type `radio` **OR** `checkbox`
2. Which are selected ie. wich have `is(':checked')` as `true`
3. and have a some class applied to it.
I come up with following code

```
 $([':radio'],[':checkbox']).each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        className = $(this).attr('class'); 
        if(className!= "")
        {   
            $('#'+className +' :input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }   
  });
```

Its workign fine but I am looking more efficient solution as I am selecting all `radio` and `checkbox` and filtering over it.
How can I combine all conditions ?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
The `radio` or `checkbox` can have ANY class ie I want to select all `radio` or `checkboxes` which are selected and have atleast one `class` applied it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This selector will find any radio or checkbox control that is checked and has some class on it.

```
$(":radio:checked[class], :checkbox:checked[class]")
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bYbnH/

If you need to avoid empty class names (where the attribute exists, but it set to an empty string, then you can use this:

```
$(":radio:checked[class], :checkbox:checked[class]").filter(function() {
    return(this.className && this.className.length != 0);
})
```

Comment: is the `:checkbox/:radio` actually needed? I guess `:checked[class]` would be enough, or is there an element that can be checked, I'm forgetting? And wouldn't it match elements with empty class attributes also?

Comment: @Yoshi - it will match an empty class.  Don't know if that's a concern of the OP or not as that doesn't occur in normal markup, though it could happen programmatically.  It is possible to have a checked attribute on other types of input controls (not sure why it would be there, but it can be) which will match the selector `:checked` so this limits it to only radio and checkboxes types.  I added a new option that filters out empty class names.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks for updating on empty `class`, I didnt thought about it

Comment: @jfriend00 it could be possible to have an empty class with just spaces. Would be better to use regexp in filter function: `return ! this.className.match(/^\s*$/) `. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
$(":radio:checked ,:checkbox:checked").hasClass("someclass")
```

after the question edit

```
$(":radio:checked[class] ,:checkbox:checked[class]")
```

Comment: Sorry for putting ambiguous question. I want to select all `radio` or `checkboxes` which are selected and have atleast one `class` applied it.

Comment: @Ajinkya - the response I provided should accomplish that for you.

Comment: @aro: The input element can have ANY class applied to it. It think your answer is specific to class with name `someClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':radio:checked,:checkbox:checked').filter(function(){
     return $(this).attr('class').length>0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':radio:checked,:checkbox:checked').filter(function (index) {

    if ( typeof $(this).attr('class') != 'undefined' )
        return true;
    else
        return false;   

}).each(function() {

   alert('i am checked and i am checkbox or radio and i have a class!');

});
```

UPDATE:

You want to use `$.filter()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/grGHa/1/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for

```
jQuery(":radio:checked ,:checkbox:checked")
  .filter(function() {
    // return true if className is not empty or just whitespace
    return ! this.className.match(/^\s*$/) 
  })
```